# AngularScreenshot- Not able to take screenshot for UI grid content

Tags: angular, screenshot, angular-ui-grid

I have implemented Angular-screenshot `npm` module, I am able to take a screenshot and Send image properly for normal content. however, I am not able to get a screenshot for my UI-grid implementation. Ui grid contents get dynamically by doing some series of API call.
Its giving me below error:

```
cannot fetch resource: http://localhost:8080/css/ui-grid.svg?#ui-grid, status: 404
fail @ vendor-2e7cab950d.js:20317
done @ vendor-2e7cab950d.js:20300
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
(anonymous) @ vendor-2e7cab950d.js:20294
getAndEncode @ vendor-2e7cab950d.js:20286
Promise.then (async)
inline @ vendor-2e7cab950d.js:20402
(anonymous) @ vendor-2e7cab950d.js:20424
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ vendor-2e7cab950d.js:20423
(anonymous) @ vendor-2e7cab950d.js:20422
Promise.then (async)
inlineAll @ vendor-2e7cab950d.js:20420
resolve @ vendor-2e7cab950d.js:20492
(anonymous) @ vendor-2e7cab950d.js:20449
(anonymous) @ vendor-2e7cab950d.js:20448
Promise.then (async)
resolveAll @ vendor-2e7cab950d.js:20446
embedFonts @ vendor-2e7cab950d.js:20133
Promise.then (async)
toSvg @ vendor-2e7cab950d.js:19895
draw @ vendor-2e7cab950d.js:19973
toPng @ vendor-2e7cab950d.js:19943
(anonymous) @ vendor-2e7cab950d.js:15266
(anonymous) @ vendor-2e7cab950d.js:10808
e @ vendor-2e7cab950d.js:10693
(anonymous) @ vendor-2e7cab950d.js:10696
setTimeout (async)
k.defer @ vendor-2e7cab950d.js:10696
f @ vendor-2e7cab950d.js:10808
download @ vendor-2e7cab950d.js:15261
fn @ VM34805:4
b @ vendor-2e7cab950d.js:10775
e @ vendor-2e7cab950d.js:10929
$eval @ vendor-2e7cab950d.js:10794
$apply @ vendor-2e7cab950d.js:10795
(anonymous) @ vendor-2e7cab950d.js:10929
dispatch @ vendor-2e7cab950d.js:5183
elemData.handle @ vendor-2e7cab950d.js:4991




 Event {isTrusted: true, type: "error", target: img, currentTarget: img, eventPhase: 2, …}
bubbles: false
cancelBubble: false
cancelable: false
composed: false
currentTarget: null
defaultPrevented: false
eventPhase: 0
isTrusted: true
path: [img]
returnValue: true
srcElement: null
target: null
timeStamp: 72291.29999998258
type: "error"
__proto__: Event
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] reproducing your issue.

Comment: And your error is self explanatory, `cannot fetch resource: http://localhost:8080/css/ui-grid.svg?#ui-grid, status: 404` means it did not find the element you're looking for.